# Hi, I have 3 dhcp servers like dhcp1,dhcp2,dhcp3 in my LAN. If client send the request for ip, which server will respond & offer the ip address

Tags: dhcp

I have 3 dhcp servers like dhcp1,dhcp2,dhcp3 in my LAN. If client send the request for ip, which server will respond & offer the ip address

Comment: How are the servers configured? Your answer depends on the configuration of those servers.

Answer (score 2):

DHCP is a broadcast, so all the servers will respond and offer a lease - granted that they have a pool to give a lease from.

The client then picks the offer that came first and acknowledges it to that specific server. The other two servers get a NACK.